# Why does the modulo operator return true?

Tags: javascript, modulo

This problem basically says to iterate over an integer, and evaluate if the number is divisible by its left-side number and if it is divisible return a Boolean array.

73312

- The first number doesn't have left-side number so its false.
- The next is 3/7 and evaluates to false and so on.

I ran the tests and everything is good, but with this number (73312) it returns true when it should return false.

Expected output `[false,false,true,false,true]`

Actual output `[false,false,true,true,true]`

```js
function divisibleByLeft(n) {

  let flag = false;
  const ansArr = [];
  const s = JSON.stringify(n);
  const arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    arr.push(parseInt(s[i]));
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let reminder = arr[i] % arr[i - 1];
    if (reminder !== 0) {
      ansArr.push(flag);
    } else {
      flag = true;
      ansArr.push(flag);
    };
  };
  return ansArr;
};

console.log(divisibleByLeft(73312));
```

Comment: Once you've set `flag = true` you never set it back to `false`

Comment: Technically, in JavaScript, it's a [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder), not modulo/modulus.

Answer (score 5):

The only time you assign `flag` to `false` is at the beginning of the function. Either assign it to false when the remainder isn't 0 as well:

```
if (reminder !== 0) {
  flag = false;
  ansArr.push(flag);
} else {
```

Or ditch it entirely and push the boolean:

```
if (reminder !== 0) {
  ansArr.push(false);
} else {
```

Or, more concisely, map the number to an array of digits and `.map` it, comparing to the previous element in the array on each iteration:

```js
function divisibleByLeft(n) {
  return [...String(n)].map((num, i, arr) => num % arr[i - 1] === 0)
}

console.log(divisibleByLeft(73312));
```

Comment: Or ditch it entirely and `ansArr.push(remainder === 0)`